# How to format External Western Digital hard disk when all NTFS boot sectors cannot be written to

Tags: external-hard-drive, ntfs, format, fat32

I want to format my external hard drive which is a Western Digital 500GB, through cmd dos command. But it fails because all NTFS boot sectors are not writable. Here are the commands I gave and what I got in return!

```
C:\Users\Stefanos&Fratzeskos>FORMAT F: /Q

The type of the file system is RAW.
The new file system is NTFS.
WARNING, ALL DATA ON NON-REMOVABLE DISK
DRIVE F: WILL BE LOST!
Proceed with Format (Y/N)? Y
QuickFormatting 476269M
Volume label (32 characters, ENTER for none)?
Creating file system structures.
The first NTFS boot sector is unwriteable.
All NTFS boot sectors are unwriteable.  Cannot continue.
Format failed.
```

Is there something I can do to format my disc?

Comment: HAVE YOU TRIED A NORMAL FORMAT INSTEAD OF AN QUICK FORMAT? (SKIP THE `/Q`). AND ANOTHER THING. WHY ARE YOU YELLING? It's much easier to read your questions if you type like a normal person.

Comment: I THINK HIS KEYBOARD DOESN'T INCLUDE LOWER CASE, BECAUSE EVEN HIS NAME IS IN ALL UPPER CASE.

Comment: WHAT @NIFLE SAID.

Comment: WONDER HOW HE GOT HIS TITLE IN ALL SMALL LETTERS

Comment: Thanks @Sathya if you took the time to reformat the question.

Comment: What operating system were you using? Were you issuing the `format` command from an elevated command prompt (if it was Windows Vista or later)?

Comment: Do you still have this issue? After 5 years?